# Can not set text dynamic in ApplicationBar Window phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I'm a new windows phone developer. I'm trying to create a menu app bar and want a dynamic changing text menu. I currently have the following code:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" x:Key="GlobalAppBar">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/home.png" x:Name="btnHome" Text="Home" Click="btnHome_Click"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</Application.Resources>
```

But in code behind I can not set text as:

```
btnHome.Text="new name";
```

I also searched using Google and found the following:

```
 ApplicationBarIconButton btn = (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar.Buttons.get'
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

1.Define the ApplicationBar in Application.Resources like what you have done.

2.Instantiate ApplicationBar in your Page with C# code:

```
ApplicationBar = App.Current.Resources["GlobalAppBar"] as ApplicationBar;
```

3.Change text of ApplicationBarIconButton dynamic:

```
ApplicationBarIconButton btn = (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];
btn.Text = "Hello world";
```